# Distribution where a parameter follows another distribution

Tags: statistics

if we have a PDF of a random variable X with a parameter, let's say $f_X(x;b)=2xb$ is it possible to find an expression for the unconditional pdf of X if the parameter b follows another known distribution?

Thanks:)

Comment: Presumably there is more detail, such as that $0\le X \le \frac1{\sqrt{b}}$ and $b>0$.  But in theory yes, and in practice yes for some distributions of $b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf of $X$ can be computed as such:

$$f_X(x; B) = \int_b f_X(x; b) f_B(b) \, db$$

Here are some readings on [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution).